# How to store a return value from python function in shell script

Tags: python, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to store python function return value in a shell variable. So far I have done something like this

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'master'
    }
    stages {
        stage('groovy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh '''
                    test=$(cd /home/simrkaur/tests/ && python -c 'import test; testt=test.Test(); testt.test1()')
                echo $test
                 '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In output I am not getting anything from echo $test. My python function is returning "sam". so sam should be printed there.
Output:

```
+ cd /home/simrkaur/tests/
++ python -c 'import test; testt=test.Test(); testt.test1()'
+ test=
+ echo
```

But it is not working.Is there any way to this.

Comment: You need to explain what `it is not working` means. What exactly do you try to *do* with the above code? What *exactly* happens when you try that? What *exactly* is *supposed to* happen, and how is that different?

Comment: You have a typo in your code where you have multiple multi-line literal strings denoted with `'''`. Fixing that should fix your issue.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Still getting the same output

Comment: `test=$(...)` captures the **output** of the program in the command substitution. Your python -c code will have to `print()` something.